# How to clear a set timeout in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
function checkStatusOfRequest(requestId) {
    var filePath = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo TESTMINE_APP_URL; ?>/ajax/check-export-status",
        data: 'requestId=' + requestId,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.exportType == 'csv') {
                filePath = $("#csvFilePath").val();

            } else if (data.exportType == 'pdf') {
                filePath = $("#pdfFilePath").val();
            }

            if (data.status == 'downloadReady') {

                fileName = data.fileName;
                $("#statusDisplay").css("visibility", "hidden");
                $("#download").css("visibility", "visible");
                $('#requestId').val(requestId);
                setTimeout(checkStatusOfRequest, 9000);


            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Format your code first

Comment: Don't just paste code please

Answer (score 1):

```
//keep the returned timeoutID 
var timeoutID =   setTimeout(checkStatusOfRequest, 9000);
....
//clear the timeoutID 
clearTimeout(timeoutID );
```

Comment: According to status of checkStatusOfRequest function  clearTimeout of checkStatusOfRequest

Answer (score 0):

You should set the timer to a variable first

```
var statusTimer = setTimeout(checkStatusOfRequest, 9000);
```

To clear timer call

```
clearTimeout(statusTimer);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds

```
var myVar = setTimeout(function(){alert("Hi")},1000);
```

The ID value returned by `setTimeout()` is used as the parameter for the `clearTimeout()` method.

```
clearTimeout(myVar);
```